# transform each data from datetime into integer

Tags: python, datetime

I'm making a new program, and I need your help!

what I'm trying to do is get each data from a datetime into an integer. for example:

My date is (this date is stored in a database, in string format, so I can't modify it):

```
Date = '2010-07-04 12:15:58'
```

I want to get this:

```
year = 2010 
month = 7 
day = 4
hour = 12
minute = 15
second = 58
```

I was thinking in doing something like this:

```
year = (int(date[0])*1000)+(int(date[1])*100)+(int(date[2])*10)+int(date[3])
month = (int(date[5])*10)+int(date[6])
day = (int(date[8])*10)+int(date[9])
hour = (int(date[11])*10)+int(date[12])
minute = (int(date[14]*10))+int(date[15])
second = (int(date[17])*10)+int(date[18])
```

This code is working, but I don't know if this is a good way to solve this or if there is another (and better) way.

thanks all!

Comment: Most programming languages have a proper datetime parsing library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) module? I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way to disassemble the datetime.

```
import datetime as dt

Date = '2010-07-04 12:15:58'
date = dt.datetime.strptime(Date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print 'Year: {}\nMonth: {}\nDay: {}\nHour: {}\nMin: {}\nSec: {}'.format(
                                                                date.year,
                                                                date.month,
                                                                date.day,
                                                                date.hour,
                                                                date.minute,
                                                                date.second)
```

Comment: with this, "date.year" will be an int 2010 or a string?

Comment: @DJ007 `date.year` will be an int. It is automatically converted to a string for the purposes of printing via `format`. If you don't want the printed format (I wasn't sure from the question), then just have `year = date.year` and you get the same as in your example.

Comment: OK thanks ! thats a much better way to do what I want !

Comment: Im getting an error while doing year = date.year. THE ERROR= AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: @DJ007 Err, are you sure you're using `date` and **not** `Date` (with the capitalised "D")? I can't see your code. If that's not the issue then you'll have to add your current code to the question so I can see it.

Comment: MY mistake, I definded date as date2 so the correct way for me is year=date2.year. Thanks !